# How do I run a php script from a remote server

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP script in mydomain.com and I need to run it in myOtherDomain.com with just pasting code in plain HTML.
Pages in myOtherDomain.com are plain html

```
 $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO nombre-tabla (nombre-columna) VALUES ('$domain')";
 $conn->close();
```

I'm looking for a way to have a kind of javascript code to copy and paste in myOtherDomain.com, similar to the code google analytics provide and you have only to copy and paste in your html pages.

Comment: You can create requests with javascript with a technique called AJAX. Be aware you need to enable Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS).

Comment: That is pseudo code? If that is real code A) `nombre-tabla` (and `nombre-columna`) must be encapsulated in backticks and B) You should parameterize your query.

Comment: You can't send PHP from the client, it needs to be on the server.

Comment: BTW, you never execute the SQL with `$conn->query($sql);`

Comment: @Barmar you can send php code from client to server and execute it - however usually it will be danger/unsecure

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Well, you need to write a script on the server that calls `eval()` to do it. So you still need to put a script there first.

Comment: The question suggests a basic misunderstanding about how PHP works in general.

Comment: @Barmar of course, server must support such "external"(from reqest) code execution...

Comment: Thanks @Daan. Do you know any example of ajax code that can help me?